# Place files into an existing folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, wix

I would like to make an installer for my custom TFS workitem control's files. I use WIX.
To make the controls work, I have to place files, into the

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Work Item Tracking\Custom Controls\.
```

Folder.

I made this directory structure in the xml:

```
<Fragment>
    <!--Microsoft\Team Foundation\Work Item Tracking\Custom Controls\.-->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="MS" Name="Microsoft">
          <Directory Id="TF" Name="Team Foundation">
            <Directory Id="WIT" Name="Work Item Tracking">
              <Directory Id="CC" Name="Custom Controls">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"/>

              </Directory>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

The problem is, that I get an error for MS,TF,WIT,CC folders during build:

```
ICE64: The directory <<id>> is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
```

Okay, I understand the error, but what if i don't want to delete these folder on uninstall?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RemoveFolder` element will only remove directories that are empty. That means it can be safely used to clean up folders in the user profile without prematurely removing the content there.